# Helm - hide "boring buffers" in helm-mini but not helm-buffers-list

Tags: helm

I'd like to filter `*foo*` buffers out of my helm-mini (`C-x b`) list, but occasionally I do need to operate on a buffer like that. The natural solution (to me, anyway) is to use helm-buffers-list (`C-x C-b`) to access those.

I successfully filtered out these buffers by adding `\*.+\*` to `helm-boring-buffer-regexp-list` but I can't figure out how to configure helm-buffers-list to include boring buffers.

Comment: You can't do that since helm-mini and helm-buffers-list work in the same way for buffers. You can use `C-c a` (`helm-buffers-toggle-show-hidden-buffers`) to toggle the display of "boring buffers".